# Which default Analyzer does Elastic Search use?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

Lets say I have a field "text" which have chat messages like "Hi how you are doing".

```
{
  "text": "Hi how are you doing"
}
```

I haven't defined the index, and let the elastic search define the index on the fly. Will elastic search use any analyzer by default on my field "text"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Standard analyzer** is default analyzer for all text fields in Elasticsearch as mentioned in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html

**As per same doc**

> The standard analyzer is the default analyzer which is used if none is
> specified. It provides grammar based tokenization (based on the
> Unicode Text Segmentation algorithm, as specified in Unicode Standard
> Annex #29) and works well for most languages.

Comment: So If no analyser while quering is specified, then Standard analyzer is used too right?

Comment: if you are using `match` query without https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html then  yes and if you are using `term` query then it doesn't uses any analyzer.

Comment: Sorry to bug you, this is kinda not related to what I aksed, but is there any way if we want to apply a analyzer on already indexed data?

Comment: @AdityaVerma would really appreciate if you can ask a follow up question like show us your mapping, tell your use case and what analyzer and what exactly you want to achieve so that I can help you better, asking all these in comments neither feasible nor philosophy of Stackoverflow

Comment: I have different question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63115252/how-to-do-keyword-extraction-in-elastic-search, can you please throw some guidance on it.